# Selenium PHPUnit 5.7 error with constructor argumet

Tags: selenium, phpunit, yii2-advanced-app

I am using Selenium stand alone server 3.11.0 and PHPunit 5.7. Found some cases like mine around but didn't found them helpful and couldn't realize the problem. What is the mystery behind the case :

```
Argument #3 (No Value) of PHPUnit_TextUI_ResultPrinter::__construct() must be a value from "never", "auto" or "always"
```

I red that my version might be old but I think `5.7` is still available for `PHP 5.6`. What I got in my composer `require-dev` section is:

```
"require-dev": {
        "yiisoft/yii2-gii": "~2.0.0",
        "yiisoft/yii2-faker": "~2.0.0",
        "codeception/base": "^2.2.3",
        "codeception/verify": "~0.3.1",
        "phpunit/phpunit-selenium": ">=1.2",
        "phpunit/phpunit": "^5.7"
    },
```

And this is my `test`:

```
<?php

require_once '../vendor/autoload.php';

    class PageAdmin extends PHPUnit_Extensions_Selenium2TestCase
    {
        public function setUp()
        {
            $this->setHost('localhost');
            $this->setPort(4444);
            $this->setBrowser('chrome');
            $this->setBrowserUrl('http://domain/');
        }
    }
```

It is in my root directory, where I made a folder ( PHPUnit ). Can someone give me advice? Thank you in advance!